# How to display uploaded text file in webpage using NODE js/html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, csv, upload

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

      <form action    =  "/submit"
             method    =  "post">
        Select a file: <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Really simple, the webpage will ask for csv file, then user presses submit. The whole point is to then display the content of that csv file in the /submit page.

Node js

```
var http = require('http');
var express= require('express')
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var app= express();
var multer = require('multer');
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//var dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index2.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});


app.post('/submit', upload.single('File'), function(req,res) {

});

//Listening to computer's IP address
app.listen(3000, "192.168.0.172");
console.log('Listening at 192.168.0.172:3000')
```

I create a side program that takes in csv file and parses it. I want this program to run on the file that the client uploads.

```
var columns = ["Parameter", "Address", "Data Size"];
require("csv-to-array")({
   file: "parse1.txt",
   columns: columns
}, function (err, array) {
  console.log(err || array);
});
```

How can i use the code above in the post function in the node js program??

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the job

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/submit', upload.single('file'), function(req,res,next) {
    fs.readFile(req.file.path, 'utf-8', function(err,data){
      if(err){
        res.end(err);
      }
      res.end(data);
    });
});
```

and add this into .html

```
<form action="/submit" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Comment: Getting this error,  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"